# Paypal IPN and Custom ID in new iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, paypal, paypal-ipn

I've been using the MPL iOS SDK for some time and now I'm trying to migrate to the new Paypal iOS SDK (Mainly because MPL crashes under iOS7).

I can't seem to find the option to use IPN (Instant Payment Notifications) in the Paypal iOS SDK as well as setting a Custom ID to be transfered to the IPN on a successful transaction. (In MPL it was under `PayPalPayment`).

Am I missing somewhere? Where did these options move to ?

Answer (score 0):

The new Android and iOS SDK's use the REST API's and there isn't yet a variable for setting a separate notification URL and custom variables - sorry.

New features are being added to the REST process and they'll be included in the Mobile SDK's.

Comment: So my only option right now is to use the old SDK (which crashes under iOS 7, By the way ...) or Implement iOS SDK with a different approach (validating the token manually on the server side etc... ) ?